# When I move files to desktop, I cannot open, delete or move them

Tags: windows-7, permissions, desktop

I have just had a new problem come up with moving files to my desktop. I am running windows 7.  If I move a file to the desktop I cannot open, move or delete it. Anything that was on the desktop until today is opening fine, but anything I move tells me I don't have permission to access. I have changed UAC and ensured that my user account has all permissions.

In the security tab under group or user names it automatically says 'No groups or users have permission to access this object. However, the owner of this object can assign permissions.'

I have tried changing ownership of the file but this didn't help either. I have downloaded unlocker and can move or delete the file using that, but I can't understand why I cannot access them.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Update - I can gain permission by changing ownership, editing permissions and adding all to my user account. So I guess what I actually need to find out is how to put this back to being the default setting for any files I move.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7) and run the following command: `"icacls %userprofile%" & icacls "%userprofile%\Desktop"` Then post here the output.

Comment: Does it happen for each files and folders?

Comment: Not sure if I've done this right but here's what I got:
C:\Users\Steve>icacls %userprofile% & icacls %userprofile%\Desktop
C:\Users\Steve NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
               BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
C:\Users\Steve\Desktop NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                       BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

Comment: @MarksPCSolution it seems to be each file and folder yes. Additionally, I just tried to bounce some music from ableton to 'my music' folder and it said I did not have permission to save there. I have changed permissions and it allowed me but not sure why it has all changed

Comment: Seems like a virus attack. If possible, reinstall Windows. It's easier that finding the problem.